# Using this result, find the sum of the series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Can you help me please?

PROBLEM: Expand the function $y = x (π - x)$ in the sine Fourier series on the segment $[0, π]$. Using this result, find the sum of the series

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty \:}\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{\left(2n-1\right)^3}$$

MY ATTEMPT:

\begin{align}
L&=\frac{b-a}{2}\\
a_0&=\frac{2}{\pi }\int _0^{\pi }x\left(\pi -x\right)\,dx=\frac{\pi^{2} }{3}\\
a_n&=\frac{2}{\pi }\int _0^{\pi }x\left(\pi -x\right)\cos\left(2nx\right)\,dx=\frac{\cos(n\pi)(\sin(n\pi)-\pi n\cos(n\pi))}{\pi n^3}\\
b_n&=\frac{2}{\pi }\int _0^{\pi }x\left(\pi -x\right)\sin\left(2nx\right)\,dx= \frac{\sin(n\pi)(\sin(n\pi)-\pi n\cos(n\pi))}{\pi n^3}
\end{align}

What do I do next, or why am I wrong?
Thanks

Comment: $\sin(n\pi)=0$  $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Yes I know, but how do I use the results of the series to find the other one?

Comment: You will need to apply Dirichlet's Theorem.